# Bash script not working, understanding variables

Tags: bash, shell-script

My bash skills are near to nil. I came up with a script to monitor the data transfer speed of my wifi interface.

```
#!/bin/bash 
rx_old=0
tx_old=0
speed() {
    read rx_bytes < /sys/class/net/wlp9s0f0/statistics/rx_bytes
    read tx_bytes < /sys/class/net/wlp9s0f0/statistics/tx_bytes
    drx=$(((rx_bytes - rx_old) / 1024))
    dtx=$(((tx_bytes - tx_old) / 1024))
   rx_old=$rx_bytes
    tx_old=$tx_bytes
    echo "$drx KB/s $dtx KB/s"  
}
while true;
do
    echo $(speed)
    sleep 1
done
```

This is not working, I mean the variable rx_old and tx_old does not seem to update. I think I am not able to change those variables from inside the function. Can anybody give me some insight on this?

Comment: How do you know they are not updated? A few suggestions for improvement: `rx_bytes=$(cat /sys/class...)`, and instead of `echo $(speed)`, just type `speed`.

Comment: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Comment: Oops, the problem is that you are running `speed` in a subshell, which does not update the *old* variables.

Comment: @berndbausch Thank you for your for help. It was `echo $(speed)` I wrote was mistake `speed` works fine.

Comment: @berndbausch, you should write an answer :-)

Comment: @berndbausch if I'm doing something like `xsetroot -name "$(speed)"` Here ASFAIK there is no other way to do this. How do I make sure the variable is updated in this case? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Replying to the above comment. A workaround is to let `speed` manipulate variables in the current shell (not in a subshell), including a variable named (e.g.) `outcome`. The function itself may be silent. Then you simply call `speed`, this updates the variables. You retrieve the result with `xsetroot -name "$outcome"`.

Comment: @pLumo but Kamil Maciorowski found it first.

Comment: @berndbausch I pass. Go ahead. There's a good general answer to the linked SU question. The answer is 97% mine and I don't feel like repeating myself here. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `echo $(speed)`. Commands inside `$(...)` are executed in a subshell, in other words in a child process of the shell that executes the script. A subshell can't change variables in its parent.

As a consequence, `rx_old` and `tx_old` in the main shell are indeed not updated. Variables with the same names are updated in the subshell, but they disappear when the subshell exits.

There is no need for `$(...)`, since all it does is echoing text that was already echoed by the `speed` function. It can be replaced by a "naked" `speed`, which runs in the main shell and therefore updates those variables.